# Boot windows install CD from GRUB: "Press any key to boot from CD or DVD..." loops back to GRUB menu

Tags: windows-10, boot, installation, grub, iso-image

I am trying to install windows from an installation image that is located on an NTFS partition [as described here](https://superuser.com/a/1355605/125048).

I had to add the UDF module, because otherwise the image just ends up being mounted with a single Readme file, stating that I need to use an OS that can read UDF.

So this is my grub menuentry configuration:

```
menuentry "Windows 10 Dell OEM ISO" --class windows --class os {
    # Insert modules needed in order to access the iso-file
    insmod part_gpt
    #insmod part_msdos

    # The image is stored on an NTFS partition.
    insmod ntfs
    #insmod ext2

    # The image is in UDF format.
    insmod udf

    # Insert module needed in order to find partition
    insmod search_fs_uuid

    set uuid="0393E9596AA4E370"
    search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid $uuid

    # Mount the iso image by addressing it with (partition)/path
    set iso=/images/MRJWFA00_W10x64ROW_pro.iso
    loopback loop ($root)$iso


    # boot (chain-load) the image using the cdboot.efi file located
    # on the win10-image
    chainloader (loop)/efi/microsoft/boot/cdboot.efi
}
```

When booting with this menu entry, I see "Press any key to boot from CD or DVD...". When I press a key, it will just loop back to the GRUB menu again. When I press not key, it will loop back to the GRUB menu as well.

So close... but completely stuck here. Any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to run Windows from an ISO. It will run the bootmgr but the the path will be lost. The only way to do it is to create a separate partition (logical or primary) and extract the ISO content to it and then point GRUB to that partition.

```
....
# ex: look on partition #2
set root=(hd0,2)
ntldr ($root)/bootmgr
```

Comment: the question was about running installer